# Why have I been banned from chat?

Tags: support, chat, moderation, chat-ban

So [I've](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/187246/humn) been banned from chat again.  For reporting a problem.
And, presumably, for being a thorn in the hide.
I sense problems before most do and didn't use offensive language this time.
Please look into this and correct.
Signed – a good guy in disguise.

Comment: At the very least, you should explain what happened. As you have described it here, it is entirely unclear what has happened and what any of us can do about it.

Comment: humn, I [did warn you](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/39978?m=46853140#46853140) not to keep bothering the Charcoal people. They don't understand you or your prose; to them you just seem to be talking gibberish, and they're used to banning gibberish on sight. I sent you an email a while ago (October) and another one just now - please respond! We should get in contact outside of SE. Signed, Rand.

Comment: To close voters: this situation is about a room which has no parent site. As such, there is no per-site meta to ask this question, so this is the proper place.

Comment: The ban is only five days, keep a stiff upper lip and you'll come through a better person in the end.

Comment: @Randal'Thor It's less that and more that Charcoal HQ is first and foremost a work room for the Smoke Detector project, so coming in there with cryptic prose is going to be seen as deliberate disruption.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### For reporting a problem

You did not report a problem with any of the programs that Charcoal uses to manage spam. So if you think you have a problem please think again and find a more suitable place for your reports.

You posted the following messages into Charcoal HQ (a room dedicated to combating spam on the SE network):

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49026506#49026506

> I'm not welcome here. But someone is stirring new spice into the stew. Notable at The Troll [chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/39978/the-troll]. Please look and solve.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49026677#49026677

> I was trying to tread brushback territory, tail between my legs, but when someone finds a new way to dig, I get riled.

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49026691#49026691

> And have other means, but am pursuing aboveground first.

The messages have nothing to do with combating spam.

The messages are also incomprehensible.

You know you are not welcome but you continue to post unwelcome messages.

You have been warned multiple times before regarding your behaviour in Charcoal HQ:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/47049636#47049636

> @humn How can I make it clear to you that this is not the place for... whatever it is you do? Dumping streams of consciousness here is unhelpful and you have been asked many times not to. Please stop.

And

https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/38212600#38212600

> @humn it's not clear what exactly you want to steam about but this room is not for that. Maybe try the Tavern for a start at least to ask for pointers

Clearly you cannot take hints.

Comment: Note: don't try your luck in the Tavern either